# centos - cant remove nginx and php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, centos

i cant start nginx , i got "Failed to start The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server."
i tried to start php-fpm and i got " Failed to start The PHP FastCGI Process Manager."
php-fpm log says : "[04-Aug-2020 12:10:11] ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '/run/php-fpm/www.sock': No such file or directory (2)
[04-Aug-2020 12:10:11] ERROR: FPM initialization failed"

also i cant remove nginx or php-fpm , tried to remove but i got "Failed: nginx.x86_64 1:1.16.1-1.el7 "

i need to completely remove both of nginx and php-fpm and reinstall it, but yum remove dosent remove this packages .

Comment: [04-Aug-2020 11:33:59] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[04-Aug-2020 11:33:59] ERROR: Unable to remove the PID file (/tmp/php-fpm.pid).: No such file or directory (2)
[04-Aug-2020 12:10:11] ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '/run/php-fpm/www.sock': No such file or directory (2)
[04-Aug-2020 12:10:11] ERROR: FPM initialization failed

Comment: 2020/08/04 11:41:53 [notice] 26041#0: signal process started
2020/08/04 11:41:53 [error] 26041#0: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)